# How to store a matrix of custom objects in C++

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a C++ class that I defined and would like to store a matrix of instances of this class. Has anyone some code samples to do so? I have found examples with vectors but I am not sure if this is the best solution or if there is something "simpler" (more like Objective-C style -> **NSArray * array**).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent copy constructor calls when using a container?  If so, review having a two dimensional vector of class pointers, where each instance is allocated from the free store.  Later on, you will have to manually release the allocated memory with your favorite traversal loop(s).  Be sure to declare a virtual destructor.  Otherwise you are risking the derived class' destructor not being called.

Answer (score 5):

There is no never "best solution" exist in this universe. There are plenty of ways to present a matrix in C++  and it's really up to you to choose.

**1. C-style naive solution**

Use multidimensional array (static or dynamic):

```
MyClass arr[size_y][size_x];

MyClass** arr;
```

usage:

```
arr[y][x] = MyClass(a, b, c);  // writing to (x, y)
```

Simple to code, poor performance (locality of references), memory leak prone (manual memory management) and error-prone (such as access out of bounds)

**2. C-style solution**

Use plain array instead of multidimensional.

```
  MyClass arr[size_y * size_x];
  arr[y * size_x + x] = MyClass(a, b, c); // writing to (x, y)
```

Cache-friendly, lil' bit harder to code, calculating index each time still can leak and error prone .

**3. C++ procedural style solution**

Same as above, but use `std::array` (for fixed size matrix) or `std::vector` (for dynamic size matrix) instead of plain arrays.

```
std::array<MyClass, size_x * size_y> arr;
arr[y * size_x + x] = MyClass(a, b, c); // writing to (x, y)
```

Cache-friendly, no leaks, out of bounds still there.

**4. Object-oriented C++ solution**

Write (templated) class with `std::array` (for fixed size matrix) or `std::vector` (for dynamic size matrix) as underlying storage. Overload `operator()`.

```
template<class T, size_t rows, size_t cols>
class Matrix
{
    std::array<T, rows * cols> m_Data;
public:
    T& operator()(size_t y, size_t x)
    {
        return m_Data[y * cols + x];
    }

    // more methods go here
}
```

usage:

```
 Matrix<MyClass, size_x, size_y> arr;
 arr(x, y) = MyClass(a, b, c); // writing to (x, y)
```

Cache-friendly, no leaks, programmer-friendly syntax. Smart! ;)

**5. Use some lib**

If you need some linear algebra specifics, like sparse matrices, or you just don't want to reinvent the wheel, go and google up some library. Here are some examples: [Boost uBlas](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm), [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/), [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). Smart, convenient, but needs some learning.

Comment: 4b: Use a proxy class which overloads `operator[]`. Have the `operator[]` of your Matrix class return a proxy. The proxy's own `operator[]` returns `T`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a matrix by nesting containers like e.g. C++11 `std::array`.

```
class Foo {
    /* ... */
};

int main() {
    // Create 3x3 matrix of Foo's.
    std::array<std::array<Foo, 3>, 3> mat;
}
```

Or by using plain old multidimensional arrays.

```
Foo mat2[3][3];
```

If you don't know the size during compile time then use `std::vector`.

```
std::size_t n = 3;
std::size_t m = 3;
std::vector<std::vector<Foo>> mat3(n, std::vector<Foo>(m));
```

Comment: Need to say, that nesting arrays is often a bad habit. They introduces convenient element access syntax as a trade off to performance. I'd used 'em only when you really have no other choice.

Answer (score -3):

If Foo is the name of your class, then this will create a matrix

```
Foo matrix[4][4]; //for a 4x4 matrix
```

OR

```
Foo **matrix;
```

And you can use **new** or **malloc** to initialise it.

Comment: The use of C arrays and raw pointers are discouraged in C++ for many reasons. -1.

Comment: **Note:** Using `malloc()` in this case would be blatantly wrong!

Comment: In my defence I would like to point out that the new operator in C++ finally boils down to a malloc call. You can look at the code for both GCC and Clang for this. Also since its just a matrix and not an object of a class there is no constructor coming into the picture.