# Deleting a 2D or 3D pointer created with new

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, delete-operator

How do I delete a 2D or 3D pointer created with new? I know a 1D pointer can be deleted by delete [] name_of_pointer.

```
// 1D pointer:
int *pt1 = new int[size];             // Creating 1D pointer
delete [] pt1;                        // Deleting 1D pointer


// 3D pointer   L: # of layers, R: # of rows, C: # of columns
int (*pt2)[L][R][C] = new int[1][L][R][C];   // L:2, R:2, C:3 (ex. below)
delete [] pt2;
```

I used this to create and delete a 3D pointer but it only removed the first two entries of pointer pt2, remaining 10 entries remained intact no matter how many times I ran the code.

Eg:

```
int B[2][2][3] = {{{0,1,2},{3,4,5}},{{6,7,8},{9,10,11}}};

int (*pb)[2][2][3] = new int[1][2][2][3];

for(int k=0; k<2; k++){
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            *(*(*(*(pb)+k)+j)+i) = B[k][j][i];
            cout << "k,j,i: " << k << "," << j << "," << i;
            cout << " " << B[k][j][i] << " " << *(*(*(*(pb)+k)+j)+i) << endl;
        };
        cout << endl;
    };
    cout << endl;
};

delete [] pb;


for(int k=0; k<2; k++){
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            cout << "k,j,i: " << k << "," << j << "," << i;
            cout << " " << B[k][j][i] << " " << *(*(*(*(pb)+k)+j)+i) << endl;
        };
        cout << endl;
    };
    cout << endl;
};
```

I got garbage values for (k,j,i) = (0,0,0) & (0,0,1) after performing delete operation on pb, rest all 10 values remain unchanged.

Comment: I'm moved. This is the first time I meet a four-stars programmer.

Comment: @YSC Technically there are no 4 star pointers in this code. `pb` is a single star pointer to a type with a high dimension array.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux My life improved greatly the day I started ignoring sentences starting by "technically". You should give it a try :)

Comment: Please don't do this.  Use a `std::vector<int>` and fake that it has multiple dimensions. ([See #4 from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23683784/4342498Z))

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You have a four-star line in the innermost loop before the deletion...

Comment: @NathanOliver This is just a sample test code for one my larger code. In my main code, I have several 3D arrays of size 1024*1024*10 which is why I was thinking of using heap storage to perform computations. Is it better to use stack storage?

Comment: @Ken `std::vector` uses "heap" storage.  It just manages it for you.  The reason I say you a single dimension vector is it keeps all the data contiguous.  A multi-dimension pointer or vector has no such guarantee.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh! really!! I didn't know that. I just started programming in C++ about 2 weeks ago and read about vectors just yesterday. Thanks for clarifying it. I thought only the things defined using new used heap storage.

Comment: @Ken `std::vector` essentially wraps `new type[]` into a [RAII type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).  It manages the memory for you so you don't have to worry about growing it or deleting the memory when done with it.  If you are thinking of using `new typr[]` you should either use a `std::vector<type>` or `std::unique_ptr<type`.

Comment: @Ken The class objects can use the heap storage internally, wrapping all of the memory management, so you don't have to manage it yourself.

Comment: Also, if you have not already I suggest you get [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on modern C++.  The language has changed a lot recently and modern C++ is so much nicer to use IMHO.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for recommending these books. I'm currently using C++ Primer Plus by Stephen Prata as a reference book.

Comment: @Ken It looks like it doesn't do much with modern C++ besides a single chapter.  You might want to find another book.

Comment: @NathanOliver Which book would you personally recommend? I mostly code numerical techniques & algorithms so don't have to do much with strings.

Comment: @Ken To back up your current book I think Effective Modern C++ (Scott Meyers) should work for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you! I'll refer it too. Also, is it advisable to use vector for all arrays and fake it as 1D arrays?

Comment: If you want a real array (stored in the "stack") then you can use a `std::array`.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is checking a deleted array's values. This is undefined behavior. There is no way to safely check the values that those elements now have as they no longer exist.

In addition `delete[]` is not required to "zero out" the objects it deletes. You can't assume that because the memory isn't modified the objects aren't deleted.

Comment: Thnx! Initially, I thought that it deleted the contents of the 3D pointer but since it only gave me garbage values for the first 2 entries on all occasions I thought something was off.